# I need to split a string including a wildcard

Tags: javascript, regex

Edit, let me give a better example.

Say this is my html

```
var innerHTML = '<ul><li>I1 some stuff</li>
<li>I1 more stuff</li>
<li>I2 even more stuff</li> etc..</ul>';
```

I need a way to split using numbers 1-9

```
var li   = '<li>I/[1-9]/ ';  // * being anything 1-9 including the space at the end
var sArr = innerHTML.split(li);
```

I thought that I could use regexp, but don't know much about it and how to implement it.  The above does not work.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If you mean split every `i`, you could do `s = s.split('i');` and `s[8]` would be the 9th element.

Comment: Do you know exactly which elements this string will be in? If so, just use `.substr()`, and extract the first and other characters.

Comment: Sorry, I totally flubbed up the code.  Fixed above.  I am splitting the html using li and one of the characters can be 1-9 (shown with *)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
var innerHTML = '<ul><li>I1 some stuff</li>
<li>I1 more stuff</li>
<li>I2 even more stuff</li> etc..</ul>';

var sArr = innerHTML.split(/<li>I[1-9] /);
```

Comment: Why do you escape the angle brackets?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a complete stab at it, if you want to break the string by the letter `I` followed by any digit `1-9`:

```
var a = str.split(/I[1-9]/);
```

For instance: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/IsEGAba/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/IsEGAba/1/edit)

```
var str = "stuffI1more stuffI2even more stuff";
var a = str.split(/I[1-9]/);
display("str: " + str);
display("a:");
a.forEach(display);
```

Displays:

```
str: stuffI1more stuffI2even more stuff
a:
stuff
more stuff
even more stuff
```

Comment: And to extend your method to be more precise based on the example in the question, `var a=str.split(/>[^<>]*I[1-9]/$`, etc...